# How to update table without adding new table on each button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 files for showing data when clicking a button.
How would I not keeping adding table when I each click the button?
I would like to get refreshed data each time when I click the button.

I have tried removing if the button id and data id equals, but it didn't work.
Is there a simple way of doing?

1. HTML based php script.
2. JS for ajax for passing id of button, getting data from PHP script.
3. PHP getting data from SQL but I will write the data for this post.

**HTML based PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>MINI TEST</title>
</head>

<style>
.oldList td{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: lightblue;
}
.oldList{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
}
.showNewData td{
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: lightgreen;
}
.showNewData{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 50px;
}

</style>

<body>

<?php

$oldList[] = array('1' => '1', '2' => 'mango','3' => '340');
$oldList[] = array('1' => '2', '2' => 'peach', '3' => '480');

    foreach ($oldList as $value){ 
        $idForList = $value['1'];
        print "<table class='oldList'>";
        print "<tr><td>".$value['1']."</td><td>".$value['2']."</td><td>".$value['3']."</td></tr>";
        print "</table>";  

        print"<button class='newData' data-name='$idForList' id='$idForList'>{$idForList}NEW DATA</button>";  
        $idForNewData = "id" . strval($idForList);
        print "<table class='showNewData' id='$idForNewData'></table>";
    }
 
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="mini_test_ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.newData').click(function(){
   
    var gotId =  $(this).data('name');
    var idForNewData =  "#id" + gotId; 

        $.ajax({
          url: "mini_test_sql.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "gotId": $(this).data("name")
          },
          success: function(data) {
              console.log("success");
              $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value){
                $(idForNewData).append("<td>" + value + "<td>");
              });     

          },  
          error: function(xhr,XMLHttpRequest,errorThrown){
              console.log("Fail");
              console.log("xhr: " + xhr);
              console.log("XMLHttpRequest: " + XMLHttpRequest);
              console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);   
          }
        });


  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 

$idForList = $_POST['gotId']; 

$productList[] = array();

$productList[0] = array(
    'id'    => "1",
    'name'  => "mango 2 ",
    'price' => "280"
);

$productList[1] = array(
    'id'    => "2",
    'name'  => "peach 2",
    'price' => "300"
);

if($idForList == 1){
  echo json_encode($productList[0]);
}
if($idForList ==2){
  echo json_encode($productList[1]);  
}

?>
```

Comment: You keep appending Empty the table. but you need trs too

`success: function(data) {
$(idForNewData).empty(); $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value){ $(idForNewData).append("<tr><td>" + value + "<td></tr>"); }); },  `

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: mplungjan> Thank you , solved this problem !

Answer (score 0):

Easy, when you get data, empty table then put your data again in it
This part of code:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value){
       $(idForNewData).append("<td>" + value + "<td>");
});
```

Should be something like this:

```
$(idForNewData).html("");
var d = "<tr>";
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value){
          d += "<td>" + value + "<td>";
}); 
d += "</tr>";
$(idForNewData).html( d );
```

Comment: Ultrazz008> Thank you , I added this code too, and it solved the problem . I didn't have the idea of adding tr, td value to variable d, so it also was helpful.

Comment: This question is a typo-type question and not necessary to be answered. It is not useful for other users - instead of answering what already was commented on the question, you could vote to close instead

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that the id selector is '#' and not '#id'.

Please try:

```
var idForNewData =  "#" + gotId;
```

As mentioned by Ultrazz008, you are just trying to add the cell (td) to the table. However, the table contains rows (tr) and either row contains the cells (td).

It's better to start IDs with letters (please, [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)).

BR

Comment: This question is a typo-type question and not necessary to be answered. It is not useful for other users